# asp.net DataGrid and forcing it to work with my existing structure

Tags: asp.net

So my existing structure is

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cotent</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The DataGrid is adding a bunch of stuff I do not desire to be there, is it possible to remove this extra information so I don't have to make heavy modifications to my CSS file?

Here is how the above table looks after DataGrid.

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_articleList" headertext="File Name" rules="all">
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td> <!-- I need this to be a TH?? -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The biggest issue here is I need the header row to be `<th>` and not `<td>`.  And I need the table to just be   the `ID` and `runat="server"` are not big deals, not sure what the `rules="all"` does.

Here is my asp.net code.

Code Behind Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("examfilemanager"));

    articleList.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles();
    articleList.DataBind();
}
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:DataGrid Enabled="false" runat="server" ID="articleList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE" HeaderText="File Name">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Write Time" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Length" HeaderText="Filer Server" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Scott what exactly did you edit ?!

Comment: Just click on the edited x mins ago link and you can see the edits. Your aspx markup wasn't indented to where it was flush with the left side, like the rest of your code snippets.  I simply fixed the indentation.

Comment: @Scott Ahh, I didn't know I could click that link for a description, thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `UseAccessibleHeader` to true:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" UseAccessibleHeader="true" ...>
```

If possible you really should use the `GridView` control instead and take advantage of the many features that aren't available to the `DataGrid` control. The traditional `DataGrid` control is more of an antiquated relic at this point.